# Unable to send excel file as attachment using MIME in python

Tags: python, email-attachments, mime

I am having a hard time figuring out why I am not able to send a working excel file as an attachment. The attachment appears in the email, however, it is not a .xlsx extension and cannot be opened with any application. I am not sure what is causing this. Here is my code, using python 3.6:

```
import pandas as pd
import smtplib
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText    
from email.mime.base import MIMEBase
from email import encoders

sender='sender@email.com'
receivers='receiver@email.com'    

#create a dataframe to send in text
d={'name':['alex','steve'], 'age':[23,45]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['Subject'] = 'Email Test subject'
msg['From'] = sender
msg['To'] = receivers

html='''
<html><p>******This is an Automated Email******</p>
<h3>Updates pending:</h3>
<p>Here is your table:</p>
{0} <p><p/><p> More text here.<p/></html>
'''.format(df.to_html())

msgText = MIMEText(html,'html')
msg.attach(msgText)

file = r'C:\Users\alo\Desktop\Python_Scripts\Excel\excel_file.xlsx'

part = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
part.set_payload(open(file, "rb").read())
encoders.encode_base64(part)
part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename=file')
msg.attach(part)

try:
  with smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) as smtpObj:
      smtpObj.sendmail(sender, receivers, msg.as_string())
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
```

Email works, text in email looks good with df in it, attachment is in the email, but it cannot be opened, not an .xlsx file. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: may be there some security issue, first you can try sending the file without the code and use simple email. if it is working then try the file zipping first then send the email using your code.

Comment: Hi yes, it does work when I use smtp. I get the issue when I introduce MIME